# gridView definitions for Column headings with mouse hover

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridView:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwAccums" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CssClass="GridView" 
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeaderRowStyle"
        RowStyle-CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle"
        EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="GridEmptyDataRowStyle"
        >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Start Date" DataField="Beg_PlanYr" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Paid" DataField="indTotPaid" DataFormatString="{0:F}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Copay" DataField="indTotCopay" DataFormatString="{0:F}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Deductible" DataField="indTotDed" DataFormatString="{0:F}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Out of Pocket" DataField="indTotOop" DataFormatString="{0:F}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div id="pnlEmptyAcums" runat="server" class="NoRecs">
                    <span style="font-style: italic">No Accumulated Totals found.</span>
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and I am trying to add definition text to its column headers on the server side:-

```
protected void gvwAccums_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = e.Row;
        bool isDataRow = row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow;
        TableCellCollection cells = e.Row.Cells;
        string allCells = string.Empty;
        string content = "";
        int lastCol = cells.Count - 1;

        content = cells[lastCol].Text.Trim();


        // Only do this to the header row, ignore data and footer rows. Adding definition to the label of each column on the Gridview of claims.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = "xxxxx ";
            e.Row.Cells[1].ToolTip = "yyyyy ";
            e.Row.Cells[2].ToolTip = "zzzzz ";
            e.Row.Cells[3].ToolTip = "fffff ";
            e.Row.Cells[4].ToolTip = "vvvvv ";
        }

    }
```

However I don't see any text when I hover over with the mouse pointer. The gridview itself works fine.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code work for me - tooltip displays when mouse hovers on Header text.

If still doesn't work, you can try with `Attributes.Add`

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("title", "xxxxx ");
```

### Here is how I test your code

[image]

```
public class Test
{
    public int Beg_PlanYr { get; set; }
    public decimal indTotPaid { get; set; }
    public decimal indTotCopay { get; set; }
    public decimal indTotDed { get; set; }
    public decimal indTotOop { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gvwAccums.DataSource = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test {Beg_PlanYr = 1, indTotPaid = 1, indTotCopay = 1, indTotDed = 1, indTotOop = 1},
            new Test {Beg_PlanYr = 2, indTotPaid = 2, indTotCopay = 2, indTotDed = 2, indTotOop = 2},
            new Test {Beg_PlanYr = 3, indTotPaid = 3, indTotCopay = 3, indTotDed = 3, indTotOop = 3},
        };
        gvwAccums.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvwAccums_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = "xxxxx ";
        e.Row.Cells[1].ToolTip = "yyyyy ";
        e.Row.Cells[2].ToolTip = "zzzzz ";
        e.Row.Cells[3].ToolTip = "fffff ";
        e.Row.Cells[4].ToolTip = "vvvvv ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I know dude. Tooltip works for my other grid view but not for this one, same method, just different names. 

Add attributes doesn't work either. Total loss of words.

Comment: i added breakpoints on the tool tip and the add attributes section of my code.. and these breakpoints are never hit. while on my other gridview, the breakpoints for the very same type of coding are hit on page load. is my code not seeing the gridview on the server side?

Comment: Look like you did not attach **gvwAccums_RowDataBound** event to **gvwAccum**. For example, `<asp:GridView ID="gvwAccums" ... OnRowDataBound="gvwAccums_RowDataBound" >`

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh snap